# Client socket.id refreshes?

Tags: javascript, node.js, sockets, socket.io

I'm trying to pass some information from `localhost:3000` to `localhost:3000/id` but whenever I visit the second url the `socket.id` changes. If you `npm app.js` you will see that the server outputs 'Client connected with id: id' twice. So the `socket.id` changes and the server passes it to the wrong socket.

Can't seem to figure what is causing the problem and am hoping you could help me out.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is probably because when you go to a new page you are also calling the socket.io client script again which will cause a new socket connection. my best advice is to get sessions hooked up to your socket io.

Comment: https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-socket.io-session is a good npm module that ive used in the last two days to do this.